Update consecutive dates for a certain amount of records
I have a MySQL 5.7 table.
There are 9000 records that I need to set consecutive dates to.
The first 300 records will have 2025-01-02.
The next 300 records will have 2025-01-03.
And so on until all 9000 have been updated, up until the final date of 2025-01-31.
Is there a way to do this with a single query?
I don't want to do this 30 times:
UPDATE table SET date = '2025-01-02' ORDER RAND() LIMIT 300;

This is what I tried:
SET @row_num = 0;
SET @start_date = '2025-01-02';

UPDATE `DISTRIBUTION`
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
    `email`, 
    @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS row_num
FROM `DISTRIBUTION`
) AS numbered_rows ON `DISTRIBUTION`.`email` = 
numbered_rows.`email`
SET `DISTRIBUTION`.`date_column` = DATE_ADD(@start_date, 
INTERVAL FLOOR((row_num - 1) / 300) DAY)
WHERE `LIST` = 'list1' AND `DOMAIN` = 'GM';

But upon trying that, it was setting the records to dates out in the 2040s and back to 1930.

You should use the same WHERE conditions in the subquery that you JOIN with.

What is necessary doing in the ORDER BY clause? That's not valid syntax.

@Barmar - typo.  I removed the ORDER BY.

I tried your query and it works as expected.

@barmar - Apparently I wasn't clear in my question - I need the dates to stop at 2025-01-31.

In my test I only had about 600 rows so I made the groups 30 instead of 300. The dates stopped at 2025-01-22 as expected.

The question was perfectly clear. Since there are 9000 rows and they're in groups of 300, there should be 30 consecutive dates.

I can't see any reason why your query isn't working, it works for me. But you can simplify it by leaving out the JOIN, and just using @row_num directly.
set @row_num = -1;
set @start_date = '2025-01-02';

update distribution 
set date_column = date_add(@start_date, interval floor((@row_num := @row_num + 1) / 300) day) 
where list = 'list1' AND domain = 'GM'
order by email;

You have to initialize @row_num to -1 because the calculation uses the value after incrementing it.
DEMO
In the linked demo, my table is smaller so I used groups of 30 instead of 300, but the principle is the same.

My apologies - I did not specify that I needed the dates to end at 2025-01-31.

Yes you did. You said they should be consecutive starting at 2025-01-02 and there are 30 dates.

Not sure why it's not working for me.  My dates are going into 2031.

I added a link to db-fiddle that shows it working.
